# Calculating similarity between rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cosine-similarity

Goal is to identify top 10 similar rows for each row in dataframe.

I start with following dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

d = {'0001': [('skiing',0.789),('snow',0.65),('winter',0.56)],'0002': [('drama', 0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',-0.42) ('winter',-0.12),('kids',0.12)],'0003': [('action', 0.89),('funny', 0.58),('sports',0.12)],'0004': [('dark', 0.89),('Mystery', 0.678),('crime',0.12), ('adult',-0.423)],'0005': [('cartoon', -0.89),('comedy', 0.678),('action',0.12)],'0006': [('drama', -0.49),('funny', 0.378),('Suspense',0.12), ('Thriller',0.78)],'0007': [('dark', 0.79),('Mystery', 0.88),('crime',0.32), ('adult',-0.423)]}
```

To put it in dataframe I do following:

```
col_headers = []
entities = []
for key, scores in d.iteritems():
    entities.append(key)
    d[key] = dict(scores)
    col_headers.extend(d[key].keys())
col_headers = list(set(col_headers))
```

populate the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_headers, index=entities)
for k in d:
    df.loc[k] = pd.Series(d[k])
df.fillna(0.0, axis=1)
```

One of the issue in addition to my main goal that I have at this point of the code is my dataframe still has NaN. This probably why my result matrix is filled with NaNs.

```
     Mystery drama  kids winter  funny  snow crime  dark sports Suspense  adult skiing action comedy cartoon Thriller
0004   0.678   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN  0.12  0.89    NaN      NaN -0.423    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
0005     NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN   0.12  0.678   -0.89      NaN
0006     NaN -0.49   NaN    NaN  0.378   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     0.12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     0.78
0007    0.88   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN  0.32  0.79    NaN      NaN -0.423    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
0001     NaN   NaN   NaN   0.56    NaN  0.65   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN  0.789    NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
0002     NaN  0.89  0.12  -0.12    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN  -0.42  0.678     NaN      NaN
0003     NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   0.58   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.12      NaN    NaN    NaN   0.89    NaN     NaN      NaN
```

To calculate cosine similarity and generate the similarity matrix between rows I do following:

```
data = df.values
m, k = data.shape

mat = np.zeros((m, m))

for i in xrange(m):
    for j in xrange(m):
        if i != j:
            mat[i][j] = cosine(data[i,:], data[j,:])
        else:
            mat[i][j] = 0.
```

here is how mat looks like:

```
[[  0.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan   0.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan   0.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan   0.  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan   0.  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   0.  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan   0.]]
```

Assuming `NaN` issue get fix and `mat` spits out meaning full similarity matrix. How can I get an output as follows:

```
{0001:[003,005,002],0002:[0001, 0004, 0007]....}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of the issue in addition to my main goal that I have at this point of the code is my dataframe still has NaN.

That's beacause `df.fillna` does not modify DataFrame, but returns a new one. Fix it and your result will be fine.

Comment: alternatively, you can use the ``inplace=True`` argument.